# php 7.4 error Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Interval as array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code

```
function merge($intervals) {
    sort($intervals);
    $j = 0;
    $tmp[$j] = $intervals[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($intervals); $i++) {
        $start = $intervals[$i][0];
        $end = $intervals[$i][1];
        if ($start <= $tmp[$j][1]) {
            $tmp[$j] = array($tmp[$j][0],$tmp[$j][1] >= $end ? $tmp[$j][1] : $end);
        } else {
            $j++;
            $tmp[$j] = $intervals[$i];
        }
    }
    return $tmp;
}
$intervals = [[10,30],[20,60],[80,100],[150,180]];
print_r(merge($intervals));
```

This is my error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Interval as array in /tmp/solution.php:7

How should I modify it so that the error is not reported in 7.4?

Comment: So far from your posted code, you have a (plural) array named `$intervals`. No where in your question do you demonstrate that you instantiated an object?

Comment: tested on php7.4 and works fine with me, please make sure that this error refer to this snippet

Comment: Agree with @OmarTammam , this code works well on PHP 7.4. The error must be somewhere else or on how you populated the `$intervals` array